# Gaussian wavepacket for $N$ identical bosons

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction

Suppose a photon is described by a wave-packet with Gaussian amplitude $A_1(x_1) = \exp\left(-\frac{x_1^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)$. How can one generalize to a system of $N$ identical photons?

One could simply write $A_N(x_1, ..., x_N) =\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}(x_1^2+...+x_N^2)\right) $ which is factorizable  as $$A_N(x_1,..., x_N)= A_1(x_1)...A_N(x_N)$$ and symmetric in every argument, as expected in a system of bosons. But are there more general ways, that may also take into account interactions between the particles?

Answer (score 0):

If the single-particle states are all identical then yes it's just the product of the states with different coordinates. If the states are different (say with different $\sigma_i$), then the state would be the sum of all permutations of products of the single-particle states.

Comment: So, for example the correct amplitude for a two-photon state would be $$A_2(x_1,x_2)=\frac{1}{2!}\left(A_{\sigma_1}(x_1)A_{\sigma_2}(x_2) + A_{\sigma_1}(x_2)A_{\sigma_2}(x_1)\right),$$ if we define $A_{\sigma_i}(x_j)=e^{-\frac{x_j^2}{2\sigma_i^2}}$.